# TabItem strange behaviour, multiple tabitems share content

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, tabs

**Change in any tab changes the other tab!!!!!!!**

Code explanation:

===================

The tabcontol's items source is bound to a collection of string having length/count as 3. So 3 tabitems are created. But they behave like one. You type in any tabitem and it will be reflected in other two tabitems.

Below is a simple xaml and code nehind.

```
<Window x:Class="TabAnalyzer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Height="30" Width="200"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

===================================================================

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace TabAnalyzer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new StringCol().strdata;
        }
    }

    public class StringCol
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> strdata
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public StringCol()
        {
            strdata = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            strdata.Add("hkhdfkshdfk");
            strdata.Add("hkhdfkshdfk");
            strdata.Add("hkhdfkshdfk");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the image having strange behavior described

[image: Change in any tab affects the other]

Could anyone please this why does this happen and how to fix this?

- For any additional information please add a comment.

*Note: I am using VS 2013*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is the xaml code for other tabs?

Comment: I have a single tabcontrol. It's items source is set to a collection, so 3 tabitems are created. But all 3 tab items are behaving like one. If you change data in any one tab item then other two are showing the same data.

Comment: You might want to read here about why this happens as well as about a possible workaround: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460989/WPF-TabControl-Turning-Off-Tab-Virtualization

Comment: Thanks elgonzo. I got the reason of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF the UI layout/control is not rebuild if the template does change. The normal behavior is to keep the template and only update the data.

In this case, the data is not binded to anything so the data owner is the UI itself. Since the UI is not rebuilded, you have this behavior.

In normal application, your "textBox" would be binded to something and this would not be a real issue.

Futhermore, Since your source is 3 exacts same string, the data source of the page does not change. String are immuable in c#. In this case, your data is 3 times the same string instance. Normally, you would bind to distinct classes. In this case, I don't think that the template data source change when you change tab.

In your xaml, you can bind your Text's textBox to "Text={Binding Path=.}" and you will keep the exact same behavior. (String immuable)

If you create a new tab with a new name (Add a new string value in your source), you will be able to "clear" the value in the TextBox when you change from or to this tab.

But the core issue here, is simply the fact that you don't bind to any real data. The data owner is the UI and you do nothing with the tab control content. You would have to attach the TabItems data to your source. (list of TabItemViewModel) If they have the same UI (Same template), they will have distinct data instance and your UI would refresh from your viewmodel data.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation. 
I know this can be fixed by binding the Textbox's Text property. But what if I want to have a RichTextBox inside my tab. 
The Document property of RichTextBox is not a dependency property, so can't bind RichTextBox. So in case of using RichTextBox how to fix this.